# Passing inflated fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Suppose I have an activity with an onCreate() and an animation doSomething(). How can I attach an inflated fragment to a view in onCreate, and pass that to my animation method? Now I know how to simply inflate a fragment via fragmentManager & fragmentTransacation, but I don't know how I can pass that to another method within that activity

```
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AnimatorSet mSetRightOut;
private AnimatorSet mSetLeftIn;

private View mCardFrontLayout;
private View mCardBackLayout;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

private SingleAnswerFragment answerFragment;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private boolean mIsBackVisible = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer_activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mCardBackLayout = findViewById(R.id.card_back);
    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.a_fragment);
    frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    frameLayout.setId(R.id.a_fragment);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(frameLayout.getId(), SingleAnswerFragment.newInstance(), "answerTag");
    container.addView(frameLayout);

    mCardFrontLayout = findViewById(R.id.card_front);

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.q_fragment, SingleQuestionFragment.newInstance());

        transaction.commit();
    }

    loadAnimations();
    changeCameraDistance();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void changeCameraDistance() {
    int distance = 8000;
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * distance;
    mCardFrontLayout.setCameraDistance(scale);
    mCardBackLayout.setCameraDistance(scale);
}

private void loadAnimations() {
    mSetRightOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.out_animation);
    mSetLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.in_animation);

}



public void flipCard(View view) {
    if (!mIsBackVisible) {
        mSetRightOut.setTarget(mCardFrontLayout);
        mSetLeftIn.setTarget(mCardBackLayout);
        mSetRightOut.start();
        mSetLeftIn.start();
        mIsBackVisible = true;
    } else {
        mSetRightOut.setTarget(mCardBackLayout);
        mSetLeftIn.setTarget(mCardFrontLayout);
        mSetRightOut.start();
        mSetLeftIn.start();
        mIsBackVisible = false;
    }


}


}
```

I'm trying to make mCardBackLayout contain my fragment. Mind you this activity has a fragment at the top which works how I want it to, and then a nested fragment that will do a card flip beneath it, which is what I'm trying to work out

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: doSomething(View yourInfaltedView){ //do actions on passed inflated view here }... Inflating is not like as u think.. your doing a transaction on a frame layout using transaction method... Inflation is just this.... **View inflatedView =  LayoutInflater.fromContext(getBaseContext).inflate(layoutResId, null);**

Comment: @DJphy in your answer, inflate(layoutResId, null) in place of the null could I call SingleAnswerFragment. newInstance()?

Comment: no that is the frameLayout obj...u will get a compiler error i guess

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with the frameLayout code? I'm trying to attach the newly instantied SingleAnswerFragment via add view method. So that I can pass my global frameLayout variable in my animation method instead of mCardBackLayout

Comment: sorry i was out... :) let me see it

Comment: one thing is that i dono what ur trying to achieve

Comment: I thought I explained it pretty straight forward. It's in the the first paragraph and again beneath the code snippet. I'm trying to pass an inflated view that contains an instantied fragment.. As of now I only get the static layout predefined in xml. When SingleAnswerFragment.newInstance() fires up, it will change the text view.

Comment: dont do new frameLayout instantiation and later add ur fragment to it

Comment: are u there... i need to ask few questions?

Comment: Sorry I'm at work, but by all means ask away and as soon as I get off, I'll respond

Comment: @DJphy what were you going to ask?

Comment: let's get into conversation

Comment: before proceeding with the solution; i need to know about ur UI and its use case

Comment: Looking back at it. I realize that I'm asking the wrong question. My ultimate goal is to populate a text view via event bus. I need to subscribe the activity, dynamically add the textview to the frame layout via register sticky